# Publish just one webform? Or precompile just one webform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, .net-4.0, web-deployment

I'm sure this isn't the first time someone asks this, but I tried doing a search and found nothing.

We have an issue with a website, and we've narrowed it down to a timeout issue with an email being sent. So I created a simple webform that sends a test email and I would like to reproduce the error with this new webform..

The issue is that since we publish the website, what's deployed to the production server are precompiled files. I don't want to publish the whole site again just to include one webform with two controls.

How can I just publish one webform? Or how can I precompile just one webform? I don't want to publish the whole site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't display any code for us to evaluate perhabs we might see the very source of your problem from the method you're using to send the email.

From experience, using SMTP in ASP Webforms usually crashed the app at some point in the lifecycle. The issue might be from time-outs or from the security configuration of your Website or the hosting enviroment.
I'll recommend you integrate the use of Email APIs to avoid these issues. Sendgrid is a good choice.

Secondly, it appears you have a small test Webform project where you expect to encounter the result again and to maybe adequately analyse the error. I recommend you do not need to deploy this test Webform to your hosting environment because as it would replace the existing site there.  While you have the option to pre-compile the site before publishing via FTP, Web deploy does the whole work for you automatically.

It's better you create a different enviroment for testing apps to prevent interference with the live version.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write some server side code, you need the recompile your website and replace the .dll in your bin folder.